# Neural network works on XOR, but not on MNIST dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to making my own neural network in Python 3. I tested it on the XOR problem, and it worked fine. Next I wanted to test it on the MNIST dataset to recognise hand-written digits. My network has the following architecture: 4 layers of 784, 16, 16, 10 neurons. The output should look like this: if the input represents the digit x (with x between 0 and 9), then output[x] should equal to one, with the other values of output equal to zero.
I have encountered some weird issues:

- the network works for 1 example if I train it with only 1 example
- the network doesn't work for 2 examples (representing different digits) if I train it with those 2 examples. The outputs look like this:

  [[0.497 0.498 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.002 0.002 0.002 0.001]] #represents a 0, so should look like [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

  [[0.497 0.498 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.002 0.002 0.002 0.001]] #represents a 1, so should look like [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
- The network works for x examples (representing the same digit) if I train it with those x examples, but only for x < 6. If x > 6, all elements of output[] are equal to 0

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def sigmoid (x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

class neural_network:
    def __init__ (self, structure):
        self.layer = []
        self.layer_a = []
        self.deltaLayer = []
        # deltaLayer[] is 1 layer shorter than layer[], since you don't need to calculate the delta of the input layer and layer[] contains the input. the delta of layer[1] is equal to deltaLayer[0]
        self.weight = []
        self.bias = []
        for i in range (len(structure)-1):
            self.layer.append(np.zeros((structure[i], 1)))
            self.layer_a.append(np.zeros((structure[i], 1)))
            self.deltaLayer.append(np.zeros((structure[i+1], 1)))
            self.weight.append(np.random.rand(structure[i+1], structure[i]))
            self.bias.append(np.random.rand(structure[i+1], 1))
        self.layer.append(np.zeros((1, structure[-1])))
        self.layer_a.append(np.zeros((1, structure[-1])))

def backpropagation(self, mInput, desired_output, learning_rate):
        self.feed_forward(mInput)

        self.deltaLayer[2] = 2 * (self.layer[3]-desired_output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer[3])
        self.deltaLayer[1] = np.dot(self.weight[2].transpose(), self.deltaLayer[2]) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer[2])
        self.deltaLayer[0] = np.dot(self.weight[1].transpose(), self.deltaLayer[1]) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer[1])

        self.weight[2] -= np.dot(self.deltaLayer[2], self.layer[2].transpose()) * learning_rate
        self.weight[1] -= np.dot(self.deltaLayer[1], self.layer[1].transpose()) * learning_rate
        self.weight[0] -= np.dot(self.deltaLayer[0], self.layer[0].transpose()) * learning_rate

        self.bias[2] -= np.sum(self.deltaLayer[2], axis=1, keepdims=True) * learning_rate
        self.bias[1] -= np.sum(self.deltaLayer[1], axis=1, keepdims=True) * learning_rate
        self.bias[0] -= np.sum(self.deltaLayer[0], axis=1, keepdims=True) * learning_rate

epochs = 5000
num_samples = 500 #number of samples for each digit
training_data = np.zeros((10*num_samples, 784, 1))
desired_output = np.zeros((10*num_samples, 10))
accuracy = 0

for i in range (0, 10): # i represents the digit
    for j in range (0, num_samples):
        training_data[num_samples*i+j] = cv2.imread('/Users/anton/Documents/machine_learning/MNIST/MNIST_Dataset_JPG_format/training_data/' + str(i) + '_' + str(j) +'.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).reshape(784, 1) # all images are stored on my computer as .jpg
        desired_output[num_samples*i+j][i] = 1.0
training_data = np.squeeze(training_data, axis=2)

nn = neural_network([784, 16, 16, 10])

for i in range (epochs):
    nn.backpropagation(training_data.transpose(), desired_output.transpose(), 0.1)

for i in range (len(training_data)):
    if (np.argmax(nn.feed_forward(training_data[i].reshape(1,784).transpose())) == np.argmax(desired_output[i].reshape(1,10).transpose())):
        accuracy += 1
accuracy /= len(training_data)

print(str(accuracy)+"%")
```

I hope everything is clear in my code. I used neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com and the videos of 3Blue1Brown on Youtube as a reference to create my code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please include your feedforward function? Your loss function is also unclear, is it just 2(obtained - expected) ? Look at the cross-entropy loss function.